# AJAX form submission issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, post

Following code are HTML markup and JS part of my signup page. I don't know what's wrong but, when I left all text inputs unfilled and click on submit button for the first time, it validates and gives error message. But when click second time it directly posts all data to php file. Please take a look at my js file (P.S. Don't pay attention to validation error messages:))

HTML markup looks like that

```
 <form id="signup_form" action="core/code/PHP/registration/signup.php" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

And js part

```
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
   fname, mname, lname, email, pass, confirm_pass;




/*VALIDATION*/

/*check if input fields empty or not*/

function vPass1() {
   var isValid = true;

   if (!fname) {
      $("#fname").attr('class', 'invalid');
      isValid = false;
   }

   if (!lname) {
      $("#lname").attr('class', 'invalid');
      isValid = false;
   }

   if (!mname) {
      $("#mname").attr('class', 'invalid');
      isValid = false;
   }

   if (!email) {
      $("#email").attr('class', 'invalid');
      isValid = false;
   }

   if (!pass) {
      $("#pass").attr('class', 'invalid');
      isValid = false;
   }
   if (!confirm_pass) {
      $("#confirm_pass").attr('class', 'invalid');
      isValid = false;
   }

   return isValid;

}

/*Validation start*/
/*check names, email, password confirmation*/

function validatePassword(pw, options) {
   // default options (allows any password)
   var o = {
      lower: 2,
      upper: 0,
      alpha: 0,
      /* lower + upper */
      numeric: 1,
      special: 0,
      length: [0, Infinity],
      custom: [ /* regexes and/or functions */ ],
      badWords: [],
      badSequenceLength: 0,
      noQwertySequences: false,
      noSequential: false
   };

   for (var property in options)
   o[property] = options[property];

   var re = {
      lower: /[a-z]/g,
      upper: /[A-Z]/g,
      alpha: /[A-Z]/gi,
      numeric: /[0-9]/g,
      special: /[\W_]/g
   },
      rule, i;

   // enforce min/max length
   if (pw.length < o.length[0] || pw.length > o.length[1]) return false;

   // enforce lower/upper/alpha/numeric/special rules
   for (rule in re) {
      if ((pw.match(re[rule]) || []).length < o[rule]) return false;
   }

   // enforce word ban (case insensitive)
   for (i = 0; i < o.badWords.length; i++) {
      if (pw.toLowerCase().indexOf(o.badWords[i].toLowerCase()) > -1) return false;
   }

   // enforce the no sequential, identical characters rule
   if (o.noSequential && /([\S\s])\1/.test(pw)) return false;

   // enforce alphanumeric/qwerty sequence ban rules
   if (o.badSequenceLength) {
      var lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
         upper = lower.toUpperCase(),
         numbers = "0123456789",
         qwerty = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm",
         start = o.badSequenceLength - 1,
         seq = "_" + pw.slice(0, start);
      for (i = start; i < pw.length; i++) {
         seq = seq.slice(1) + pw.charAt(i);
         if (
         lower.indexOf(seq) > -1 || upper.indexOf(seq) > -1 || numbers.indexOf(seq) > -1 || (o.noQwertySequences && qwerty.indexOf(seq) > -1)) {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }

   // enforce custom regex/function rules
   for (i = 0; i < o.custom.length; i++) {
      rule = o.custom[i];
      if (rule instanceof RegExp) {
         if (!rule.test(pw)) return false;
      } else if (rule instanceof Function) {
         if (!rule(pw)) return false;
      }
   }

   // great success!
   return true;
}




function vPass2() {


   if ($.isNumeric(fname)) {
      $("#fname").attr('class', 'invalid');
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Ad ancaq hərflərdən ibarət olmalıdır"
      });
      return false;
   }

   if ($.isNumeric(lname)) {
      $("#lname").attr('class', 'invalid');
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Familiya ancaq hərflərdən ibarət olmalıdır"
      });
      return false;
   }

   if ($.isNumeric(mname)) {
      $("#mname").attr('class', 'invalid');
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Atanızın adı ancaq hərflərdən ibarət olmalıdır"
      });
      return false;
   }

   if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Email ünvanınızı düzgün daxil edin"
      });
      $("#email").attr('class', 'invalid');
      return false;
   }


   if (pass != confirm_pass) {
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Şifrə ilə təkrar şifrə üst-üstə düşmür"
      });
      $("#pass").attr('class', 'invalid');
      $("#confirm_pass").attr('class', 'invalid');
      return false;
   }

   if (!validatePassword(pass)) {
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Şifrə minimum 2 hərif və 1 rəqəmdən ibarət olmalıdır."
      });
      $("#pass").attr('class', 'invalid');
      $("#confirm_pass").attr('class', 'invalid');
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}

function validate() {
   if (vPass1()) {
      if (vPass2()) {
         return true;
      }
   } else {
      $.notifyBar({
         cls: "error",
         html: "Qırmızı ilə qeyd olunan xanalara tələb olunan məlumatları daxil edin"
      });
      return false;
   }
} /*Validation End*/



$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#signup_form').get(0).reset()

   $("#signup_form").submit(function (e) {
      fname = $("#fname").val();
      mname = $("#mname").val();
      lname = $("#lname").val();
      email = $("#email").val();
      pass = $("#pass").val();
      confirm_pass = $("#confirm_pass").val();



      //check the form is not currently submitting
      if ($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting') {
         var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method');

         //add status data to form
         form.data('formstatus', 'submitting');
         if (validate()) {
            //send data to server for validation
            $.ajax({
               url: formUrl,
               type: formMethod,
               data: formData,
               success: function (data) {

                  //setup variables
                  var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
                     cl, text;

                  //response conditional
                  switch (responseData.status) {
                  case 'error':
                     cl = 'error';
                     text = 'Qeydiyyat zamanı problem yarandı';
                     break;
                  case 'success':
                     cl = 'success';
                     text = 'Qeydiyyat uğurla başa çatdı';
                     break;
                  }


                  $.notifyBar({
                     cls: cl,
                     html: text
                  });
               }
            });

            //prevent form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
         } else {
            return false
         }
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: Are you using both functions to validate I am not clearly sure what executes after what but i would recommend checking function return value after second click it might be making it true

Comment: vpass1 -> checks if values empty or not, vpass2-> checks more detailed, password, email, .. other stuff. just read the code. all clearly described in comments too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two plugins may greatly simplify this for you:

- [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
- [jQuery Form Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

If you are using ajax to submit a form, I highly recommend the first one. It will save you a lot of code and frustration.

Comment: i already did this work, don't want to rebuild whole js. There 1 mini bug that I can't find exactly where i did wrong

Comment: I'd want to use form plugin but need help. My js is not very well